# How can I used XSLT to add alt text to an image file using a spreadsheet?

Tags: xslt, spreadsheet

I need to write an XSLT script where using a spreadsheet (which I converted to HTML) it looks for an image file name in column B and then adds the alt text from column C.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" designation="" enumeration="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" title="default" href="../../assets/css/main.css" />
        <title>lsac790101</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol class="ktp-question-set">
            <li property="ktp:question" typeof="ktp:Question" class="ktp-question">
                <ol class="ktp-answer-set" data-studentresponses="172">              
                    <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer" data-percentresponse="2">
                        <img src="../../img/chapterpreptest79/lsac790101-a.gif" data-graphic-ref="lsac790101-a.gif" alt="" />                      
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

So in this instance I need the script to locate lsac790101-a.gif in column B of the spreadsheet and add the alt text from column C in between the quotes in `alt=""`.

I need it to look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" designation="" enumeration="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" title="default" href="../../assets/css/main.css" />
        <title>lsac790101</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol class="ktp-question-set">
            <li property="ktp:question" typeof="ktp:Question" class="ktp-question">
                <ol class="ktp-answer-set" data-studentresponses="172">              
                    <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer" data-percentresponse="2">
                        <img src="../../img/chapterpreptest79/lsac790101-a.gif" data-graphic-ref="lsac790101-a.gif" alt="Nottingham, Lakeville, Oldtown, Hidden Hills, and Sunnyside" />                      
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my spreadsheet file which I converted to HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="tableizer-table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="tableizer-firstrow">
                    <th>contentItemName</th>
                    <th>image name</th>
                    <th>Alt Text</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>lsac790101</td>
                    <td>lsac790101-a.gif</td>
                    <td>Nottingham, Lakeville, Oldtown, Hidden Hills, and Sunnyside</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table></body>
</html>
```

Is that possible to do?

Comment: You ask about a spreadsheet and then you show an HTML code snippet? In your example HTML what is column B, what is column C? You say you need to look for an image. What do you consider to be an image? Any <img> in your HTML?

Comment: In the spreadsheet, column B would show the file name of the image which is represented in the HTML. For example, in the above HTML lsac790101-a.gif is the file name found in the spreadsheet. In column C there is alt text I need to place in the HTML in the alt text field.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing ALL  the relevant code (as code, not pics), incl. the input, your current XSLT and the expected output.

Comment: And your spreadsheet is an Excel file? From my perspective the easiest way to do this would be to export the spreadsheet to an XML file containing value pairs built from columns B and C. Then write an XSLT transformation that would go through your HTML and use the data from the exported spreadsheet XML to fill in the alt="" value.

Comment: I updated the post to include the full HTML, how I need to look after running the script, and the data spreadsheet that I converted to HTML. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way this could be done :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="spreadsheet" select="document('spreadsheet.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xhtml:img/@alt">
        <xsl:variable name="imgName" select="../@data-graphic-ref"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="alt" select="$spreadsheet//xhtml:td[.=$imgName]/following-sibling::xhtml:td[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDkx/2

Or more efficiently using a key :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="spreadsheet" select="document('spreadsheet.xml')"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="imgTD" match="xhtml:td" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xhtml:img/@alt">
        <xsl:variable name="imgName" select="../@data-graphic-ref"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="alt" select="key('imgTD',$imgName,$spreadsheet)/following-sibling::xhtml:td[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDkx/4